# Painting BufferedImage Performance

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, swing, paintcomponent

I have a Java application that has a few JPanels that each performs a lot of painting and I'm getting **alot** of performance issues. I'm using the below technique in an attempt to not suffer as much which is to just paint the JPanels content to a BufferedImage only when something on the Panel has changed rather than doing it when the main window calls a repaint. When there's a few things being changed in each panel the application slows and the animation becomes very jittery.

I check the CPU and its only at like 5% yet the updates are appearing very jittery when there's a few updates going on. Is there something that could be affecting this, I would only expect jittery issues when the CPU becomes stressed.

```
public class myClass extends JPanel {
private BufferedImage bImage;


private void updateImage() {
    BufferedImage temp= new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = temp.getGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    //Do lots and lots of drawing on g with other bufferedImages and lines and text etc

    synchronized (bImage) {
        bImage = temp;
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    synchronized (bImage) {
        g.drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, this);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using double buffering? - it could help

Comment: This doesn't look kosher to me with your not calling the super's paintComponent method and with your synchronization. Better if you created and posted a [minimal example program](http://sscce.org).

Comment: How often are you painting the `JPanel`? Are you drawing in a fixed interval?

Comment: Swing already uses double buffering, so I don't know what benefit your approach is giving you. What calls the updateImage() function?

Comment: @Toumash Swing uses double buffering automatically.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Indeed, Swing uses double buffering. Yet, if your painting operations are rather complex and involve lot's of computation, but you only update the display occasionally, this technique makes your application run faster (mainly during repaint operations that were not triggered by the code itself but by an external event, such as a resize of a the frame).

Comment: The use of the `synchronized` keyword is useless here

Comment: ^What others said, plus: You should probably not create a new BufferedImage each time. You can re-use the old one, as long as the size does not change. Although it's not relevant here: You should also call `g.dispose()` at the end.

Comment: It's difficult to see the problem in provided code; but I would recommend reading up on this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html

There are a lot of framerate-saving features described there.

Comment: Additionally, if this is an animation, you might consider timing your drawing to a frame rate and yielding periodically. synchronized(...) implies that you're running a few threads, and if one of them hogs bandwidth then you will definitely have frame rate issues.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to tell what the problem is here, but if you're concerned about framerate, then I suggest reading one of Andrew Davison's works, specifically chapters two and three. Draft chapters are available here: http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/

While Swing is tailored to be lightweight, if you're doing an unusual amount of animation with it, there are additional considerations. You'll need to time your drawing to a frame rate, yield periodically, and possibly even run a UPS timer in addition to FPS. It's still quite possible, and you're moving in the right direction.

Sorry that I can't be of more help. Best of luck.